# Using different content object passed from Views to Template depending on what button user presses

Tags: django, ajax, django-templates, django-views

I currently have one model called `Comments`.

After entering in a youtube Channel in a form, the user is taken to the index template that shows all the comments on that youtube channels videos that includes one of three key words (Keyword A, Keyword B , Keyword C).

I would like to add a feature so there are three links/buttons on the top of the page (each for one of the keywords).

The user can press that link and without page reload (does this mean I will need AJAX?) see the comments with that keyword, instead of all comments with any of the three keywords.

I am currently sending four content variable objects from views to the template (one with all the comments and three other objects each that just contain the comment objects for that keyword).

So the template has access to the data I need, I just need to make it so that when one of the links/buttons are clicked, it only shows that content.

Views

```
def addTodo(request):

    new_item =Channel(channel=request.POST['channel'])

#if channel exists render page with comments
   if Channel.objects.filter(channel=new_item.channel).exists():
       channel_obj=Channel.objects.get(channel=request.POST['channel'])
        comments_object=Comments.objects.filter(channel=channel_obj)
        comments_objectA=Comments.objects.filter(channel=channel_obj, key="keywordA")
        comments_objectB=Comments.objects.filter(channel=channel_obj, key="keywordB")
        comments_objectC=Comments.objects.filter(channel=channel_obj, key="keywordC")

        return render(request, 'todo/index.html', {'comments_all': comments_object, 'commentsa': comments_objectA,'commentsb': comments_objectB,'commentsc': comments_objectC})
```

Index Template

```
#three buttons/links on top to allow user to sort..the part Im not sure how to do:
<button type="button"onclick="justshowrelatedcomment>KeywordA!</button>
<button type="button"onclick="justshowrelatedcomment>KeywordB</button>
<button type="button" onclick="justshowrelatedcomment>KeywordC</button>

#the comment structure, would want to replace comments_all with whatever button is clicked on.
<div class="new_comment">

    <!-- build comment -->
    {%for a in comments_all%}
    <ul class="user_comment">

      <!-- current #{user} avatar -->
     <!-- the comment body --><div class="comment_body">
        <p>{{ a.question }}</p>
      </div>



     </ul>
     {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm quite stuck.. Is this possible without Ajax?

If Ajax is my only/best option, how should I go about that?

I was using this solution to avoid ajax, as I couldn't figure out how to use ajax.

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without ajax, but it does not reduce the size of loaded page. The non-ajax client-side solution is to assign each comment element a class or attribute based on its keyword - here you have used a `<ul>` element with `user_comment` class already.

So try to put the keyword as an attribute or class to your comment divs. Then you can select and then hide or show each keyword class of comments using javascript coding.

It can be done in different ways but it would be easy using pure js so I am putting the template for the implementation:

```
<!-- toggling comments -->
<script>

function toggle_keyword(keyword) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.user_comment').forEach(function (e) {
        e.style.display = 'none'; 
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.' + keyword).forEach(function (e) {
        e.style.display = 'block'; 
    });
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="toggle_keyword('KeywordA');">hide/show KeywordA!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="toggle_keyword('KeywordB');">hide/show KeywordB</button>
<button type="button" onclick="toggle_keyword('KeywordC');">hide/show KeywordC</button>


#the comment structure, would want to replace comments_all with whatever button is clicked on.
<div class="new_comment">

    <!-- build comment -->
    {%for a in comments_all%}
    <ul class="user_comment {{ a.key }}">

      <!-- current #{user} avatar -->
     <!-- the comment body -->
      <!-- here I added a.key as a class to the div -->
      <div class="comment_body">
        <p>{{ a.question }}</p>
      </div>



     </ul>
     {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks mate, then it seems Ajax would be the most efficient/smartest option?

Comment: Not really. If your users are gonna load the full result at first and it does not slow down their browser doing redundant consequent ajax calls won't be efficient.

Comment: For some reason I can not get the Jquery to work in my project..I have no idea why. JS works but the JQ won't load.  I put the exact script for JS you had (and have tried others) in my html head with no success. The other problem is I need a solution that when you click one of the three buttons, the other two will go way automatically (aka you don't have to manually press the others again)

Comment: Failing to embed JQuery is defenitely a separate issue. But for the independance of the answer I edited my answer to use pure (raw) js.

Comment: thanks I got the Jquery working now...(it "randomly" started working).  Any thoughts on how I would do the functionality I am trying of pressing one button and it would hide the other two automatically? I only want the user to see one category at a time..

Comment: It's simple like the current answer I posted you can firstly hide elements of class `user_comment` and then show the elements of class `KeywordA` for example. However the edited answer now works without need to JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Ajax will be best option for you. You just need to post one flag while clicking button with using ajax. On that flag basis you can decide which data you want to pass for your html

```
HTML
<button onclick="justshowrelatedcomment('A')">KeywordA</button>
<button onclick="justshowrelatedcomment('B')">KeywordB</button>
<button onclick="justshowrelatedcomment('C')">KeywordC</button>

<script>
function justshowrelatedcomment (flag) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'addTodo',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       flag: flag
    },
    success: function(data){
        return data;
    }
});
}
</script>

View
def addTodo(request):
    flag = request.POST['flag']
    new_item =Channel(channel=request.POST['channel'])
```

Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: awesome think I got the jist.. in my views I would just need one comments object then and set key to flag?  It seems I got a syntax error.         comments_object=Comments.objects.filter(channel=channel_obj， key=flag)